# Linux: Disabling interrupt from interrupt handler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I am writing a Linux device driver which needs to wait for an interrupt (triggered by changes in a GPIO line), and, once the interrupt happens, disable the interrupt until certain conditions are met.

I have tried calling `disable_irq_nosync` from the handler. Later, when I want to process this interrupt again, I would call `enable_irq` to reenable it. However I have found that if the GPIO changes while the interrupt is disabled, this seem to be internally detected by the kernel and would result in the interrupt firing immediately as soon as I call `enable_irq`.

Why is this happening, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Let's try to fix gpio interrupt enable function to clear interrupt pending before enabling the interrupt. But probably you have interrupt per bank and the gpio line is recognized in software loop. This case is more complex. Are you using edge or level trigger?

Comment: I tried both (edge and level); in both cases I would get an extra interrupt as soon as I reenable.

Comment: So you must be using gpio_to_irq to enable gpio in interrupt mode. So why dont you free it using free_irq and then request it again.

Comment: @sumeet_Jain: free_irq should be avoided if module driver is not going to be unload. Moreover I don't think it helps - the functions are rather for resources managing.

Comment: There should be changed CPU / mach interrupt support code. You can try to block the selected interrupt by software and do not disable its mask in hardware. Unfortunately this solution will cause additional CPU load.

Comment: You can also check if changing interrupt mask is allowed by hardware before interrupt pending is confirmed/cleared. Let's try workqueue or tasklet as interrupt bottom-half to disable the interrupt mask. However I'm afraid it is not the issue.